# Contactform 7 Placeholder Validation

Tags: forms, wordpress, validation, contacts

I'm using Contactform 7 for Wordpress. I've edited the text.php and textarea.php to enable the use of placeholders. That works fine.

But, the validation isn't working for some input fields, 'cause the validation thinks the placeholder is the actual text being validated. And yes, ofcourse that validates true 'cause it's not empty.

My input fields with placeholders are as follows:

- Your name
- Your e-mailadress
- Your telephone number

and so on.

In contactform 7's scripts.js I want the validation to check if the input isn't the same as the placeholder. So if the input value is the same as the placeholder value, do the CF7's error validation.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

In scripts.js of the contactform 7 plugin folder

Change this:

```
var submit = form.find('input:submit');
        if (! submit.length) return;
```

with this:

```
var submit = form.find('input:submit');
        if (! submit.length || submit == this.find('[placeholder]').wpcf7Placeholder()) return;
```

Comment: This gives a JavaScript error when clicking in a form field. `this.find` should be `$(this).find`. Also, this script doesn't seem to help.

Comment: pretty sure the plugin was updated once or twice since january 2014 ;)